# How to compare list items in custom adapter in Android

Tags: android, custom-adapter

I have a custom adapter MyAdapter which displays items from a dynamic list(list2).. The list shows Area, location and there corresponding total items. there can be n number of similar area and location. I want to show a row "subtotal" which adds the corresponding total items of Similar Areas. Till now I'm able to show sorted items and "Total" items at end.

[image]

Now I want to display "subTotal" row after items of similar Area.
[image]

I don't know how do I compare each row till I get different Areas, in my Custom Adapter. Here's the code for my Adapter:

```
private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private ViewHolder holder = null;

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!list2.isEmpty())
            return list2.size();
        else
            return countItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (!list2.isEmpty())
            return list2.get(position);
        else
            return countItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            final ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.activity_search_group_row, null);

            holder.text_area = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.edtTxtRef);
            holder.text_loc = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.edtTxtName);
            holder.text_total = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.edtTxtPrice);
            holder.total_lly = (LinearLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.total_lly);
            holder.txtSubTotal = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtSubTotal);
            holder.txtCount = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtCount);
            holder.txtCountTotal = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.txtCountTotal);
            holder.sum_lly = (LinearLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.sum_lly);
            holder.top_lly = (LinearLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.top_lly);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        System.out.println("=====*********adapter*********======");
        int total1 = 0;
        if (!locList.isEmpty() && !areaList.isEmpty()) {
            if (!list2.isEmpty()) {
                if (list2.size() - 1 == position) {

                    for (int k = 0; k < countItems.size(); k++) {
                        total1 = total1 + countItems.get(k);
                    }

                    lastRow = true;
                }

            }

            holder.text_area.setText(list2.get(position).getArea());
            holder.text_loc.setText(list2.get(position).getLocation());
            holder.text_total.setText(String.valueOf(countItems.get(position)));
        } else {
            searchList.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(
                    android.R.color.transparent));
            searchList.setDividerHeight(0);
            // when area and location spinners are null
            if (locList.isEmpty() && areaList.isEmpty()) {
                if (countItems.size() - 1 == position) {

                    for (int k = 0; k < countItems.size(); k++) {
                        total1 = total1 + countItems.get(k);

                    }

                    lastRow = true;
                }

                holder.top_lly.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
        if (lastRow) {

            holder.sum_lly.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.txtCountTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total1));
            holder.txtCountTotal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            lastRow = false;
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView text_area, text_loc, text_total, txtSubTotal, txtCount,
                txtCountTotal;
        LinearLayout total_lly, sum_lly, top_lly;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to simplify the logic, create separate arraylists for separate area containing object of that particular area only, this will much help you to simplify it and shortlist it

Comment: But how should I compare every area from that list so that as soon as I get different Areas, I can show subTotal row?

Comment: i.e if(list1.get(position).getArea().equalsIgnoreCase(list2.get(position).getArea))
{ //do something when area is same
}

Comment: @SheenaTyagi i think you would be better off if you sort the array first, and after that it will be very easy.

Comment: @SheenaTyagi : Solutions given below may not work, since you can't short an ArrayList having unknown values to separate it

Answer (score 0):

You can have a POJO with attributes like area, location, and total. Then create a map of `<String,List<YourPojo>>` and populate it with area as the key and the List of POJO as value. Here you will get the values separated by area.

As an example, it will look like:

```
area1 -> [{area1,loc1,20},{area1,loc2,10}] 
area2 -> [{area2,loc1,1},{area2,loc2,10}]
```

and so on.

In this way you will get different Lists for different keys.

Then iterate the keySet of the map and for every key show the value in different table rows.

Once display of one key is complete, create a row for subtotal for that particular key and then continue with the next key.

I hope this helps!

Comment: OP already have the POJO, didn't see? Your answer does not relate to OP's question anyway

Comment: @BhavikMehta If I am not mistaken the original question is  "I want to show a row "subtotal" which adds the corresponding total items of Similar Areas. " and this answer pretty well solves that. Can you explain why you think it does not solve the issue?

Comment: i think the question is "How to compare list items in custom adapter in Android"

Comment: Well if you read the question, the requirement is to show subtotals after showing data for an area. OP took comparison as an approach to get to the solution, but that need not be the case. It is clearly said that "Now I want to display "subTotal" row after items of similar Area. " this resulted in this post. However, I am happy to remove it OP confirms it is off topic :)

Comment: @BhavikMehta I've mention in my question that I've already sorted my list. I want to show subTotal row only

Comment: @SheenaTyagi: its fine if you have a sorted list, but i was suggesting an optimized wat, however, Swagata's solution is also nice, you can have a hashmap containing particular area's sorted lists. according to me, if you will separate objects area wise, it would be much easier for you to count and show subtotals

Answer (score 0):

You must sort your list by a custom comparator!
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Create a class and implement the Comparator-Interface. Then you can define your own sorting-rules.

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<MyListObjectType> {

@Override
public int compare(MyListObjectType o1, MyListObjectType o2) {
if (o1.getTotal() > o2.getTotal()) {
  return 1;
}
if (o1.getTotal() < o2.getTotal()) {
  return -1;
}
if (o1.getTotal() == o2.getTotal()) {
  return 0;
}
}
}
```

Use the comparator with:
        Collections.sort( list, new MyComparator() );

An alternative is the implementation of the comparable-interface for your objects in your list.

Answer (score 0):

> You must have a list which contain unique Model object based on area and location so you must override equal and hashcode method
>
> let it is your model

```
class Model {
String area;
String location;
int count;

Model(String area,String location) {
    this.area = area;
    this.location = location;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public String getArea() {
    return area;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this) {
        count = 1;
        return true;
    } else if (o instanceof Model) {
        Model t = (Model) o;
        if (t.getArea().equalsIgnoreCase(getArea()) && t.getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase(getLocation())) {
            count++;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return super.hashCode();
}
```

}

> For Example modelList  hold the data
>
> use list to show data it will hold unique data based on area and location and also have total count pass it to adapter

```
     ArrayList<Model> model = new ArrayList(); //you have all data with same area and location
    ArrayList<Model> list = new ArrayList(); //it will hold total area with same area + location

    for(int i=0;i<model.size()-1;i++){
        Model t = model.get(i);
        for(int j=i+1;j<model.size();j++){
            Model m = model.get(j);
            if(!t.equals(m)){
                list.add(t);
            }else{
                if(!list.contains(t)){
                    list.add(t);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```